# Loading image being displayed only on the 1st result in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Loading image being displayed below the button of 1st result in while loop no matter which button is clicked from which result. For example, if I click submit button on the first result the loading image is displayed below it. That's okay. But when I click on the submit button of any other result except the first then also the loading image is displayed below the first result only and not below the submit button of that particular result.

```
<?php while($a = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mbs_id; ?>" class="memid">
        <select class="validity" class="upgrade-valsel">
            <?php while($mv = $mval->fetch()){ extract($mv); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $mv_id; ?>"><?php echo $mv_validity; if($mv_validity == 1){ echo " month"; }else{ echo " months"; } ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Upgrade" class="submit">
        <div class="center-align" style="margin-left: -20px"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="auto" id="loading-rent" style="margin-right: 0px; height: 40px"></div>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function () {
        var dataString = {
            memid: $(this).parent().find(".memid").val(),
            memname: $(this).parent().find(".memname").val(),
            validity: $(this).parent().find(".validity").val()
        };
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to ' + dataString.memname + '?',
            buttons: {
                confirm: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "upgrade-process.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: true,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#submit").hide();
                            $("#loading-rent").show();
                            $(".message").hide();
                        },
                        success: function (json) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                                $("#submit").show();
                                $("#loading-rent").hide();
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    });
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.classes` when it comes to generating a number of elements with a loop.

Use `#id` for unique elements.

**To fix your code do the following:**

1. add and fix any missing class
2. replace all id attributes in your code with class
3. use event delegation to listen for click event on any submit button. Read the following: [jQuery API Docs on event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: when I used class then on click all the image opened when when I clicked on any of the button (with all images I mean all loading image that was under each button in the while loop). Should I use a unique I for them? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

On the following line you have set an `id` tag for the loading image; this has to be unique for each iteration of the while loop otherwise you get problems like you're experiencing. Either use unique ids and/or use javascript to select the nearest loading image to display.

```
<div class="center-align" style="margin-left: -20px"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="auto" id="loading-rent" style="margin-right: 0px; height: 40px"></div>
```

Comment: Your advice is good. However, it's not the cause of OP's problem: it would only become a problem if they used that `id` for selecting, because it will always return the first item with that `id`, but that's not currently happening.

Comment: But that is what the user is experiencing. He says only the first loading image is displayed when the submit button is clicked, regardless of which one is clicked. :)

Comment: when I used class then on click all the image opened when when I clicked on any of the button (with all images I mean all loading image that was under each button in the while loop). Should I use a unique I for them? if yes, then how?